# MySQL indexes and OR operator

Tags: mysql

Ok so I have a table over here and I've set a primary index on the auto incremented column `id`. However occasionally I will need to search by another column named `owner`, since multiple items can have the same owner I can't put a unique index so I went ahead and just put an `index` index. I ran a query

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE owner = 15 OR owner = 16`

Then for possible keys I get `owner` as expected, and for used keys I get `NULL`. Which is I guess because I have too little rows, however if I run

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE owner = 15`

For possible keys I get `owner` and for used keys I also get `owner`, with the same amount of rows.

So this made me unsure whether this index is going to be useful or not in a larger scale and in case this index will not be useful in an `OR` condition, can you guys please tell me how I must index the table so that it won't go through all records in case of an `OR`.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL optimizer doesn't use an index if the values you search for occur in a significantly large portion of the table. In my experience, "significantly large" means about 20% of the table.

So it could be that owner 15 is somewhat rare, but owners 15 and 16 together cross the threshold, so they represent a large part of the table, and the optimizer decides to do a table-scan or an index-scan instead.

For example, looks at what's reported in the `rows` field of your EXPLAIN. If the optimizer thinks that number of rows examined is over 20% of the size of the table, then that's what's going on. Remember that the `rows` reported here, and in `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, are only a rough estimate.

I have seen cases where this behavior of the optimizer is not the right choice, and it would be better to use the index. In that case you can make the optimizer think of a table-scan as prohibitively costly:

```
SELECT * FROM table FORCE INDEX(owner) WHERE owner = 15 OR owner = 16
```

Comment: Basically what I was asking was if `OR` made any difference to the way the index is used, and particularly if it would cause the index to not be used, since I'm not looking for one value

Comment: If the query uses an index, `OR` makes it a *range* query instead of a *ref* query, so yes it's different but still benefits from the index.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the index will be quite useful when the table is larger.

I suggest adding a enough test data so that the entire table doesn't fit in memory then retest.